# Deploy ASP.NET Core app with Angular on IIS

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis

I'm new to the Angular world and I'm trying to deploy an ASP. NET Core app with IIS in a local server. My solution has these projects

[image]

When I try to do a HTTP request (e.g. `/api/Categories`), in debug mode, everything works fine.

Now, when I publish the app in local server, I am able to see the HTML pages, copying the files in `dist` folder to the root folder of the server, but every HTTP request returns another HTML page that seems to be `index.html` .
Here another image:
[image]

I've spent 2 days searching on the internet, finding nothing that works.
I tried changing proxy settings, redirecting options, but nothing. Which can be the problem?

File `Web.config`

```
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

File `Startup.cs`

```
 public class Startup
{
    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("https://prf.icecat.biz");
                              });
        });

        // services.AddResponseCaching();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "api/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is likely coming from the middleware pipeline configuration. Can you show us the code of your Startup class?

Comment: @J.Loscos added the code

Comment: I don't see any mistake in your Startup class. Do you have some url rewriting rules on your IIS configuration or your web.config?

Comment: @J.Loscos I added the web.config code, I tried everything on this file. Now with this code, the request returns 404.

Comment: You can try removing the   <rewrite> node from your web.config. The Startup already does the rewriting to the index.html

Comment: @J.Loscos same problem, the request returns html

Comment: @LucaSantolini - have you found a solution? I am struggling with the same problem and would greatly appreciate your expertise!

Comment: @CarsonWiens Yeah, I had to reinstall .NET Core hosting bundle from Windows Server and then I checked the output folder because I had one more folder in "dist"

Comment: Thanks for the help! In my project, the problem was something different.
In production, the server was sending back a 500 error, but angular caught it and decided to serve index.html as a replacement for the server's 500 response.

Comment: @CarsonWiens did you find a solution?

Comment: @LucaSantolini, yes. It's explained in the comment above.
Angular was catching a 500 error sent by the server, and instead trying to serve index.html.
It's supposed to be a helpful feature, but it didn't work out that way in this situation.

To fix the problem, I fixed my backend code so it didn't throw HTTP 500 errors.

Comment: I think you don't need both `services.AddControllersWithViews();` and `services.AddControllers();`. The first one already does everything that the second one does and more.